# Avoid to consider intersecting on the edge using IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, html, intersection-observer

I have sequentially divs with height 100vh, I want to know which of them are visible on the viewport.

I'm using `IntersectionObserver` and it console when isIntersecting is true.

In the example second div is consoled as fired, but this one is hide for the viewport (is on the edge), when I add `margin-top: 1px` is not consoled. ¿Why this behaivour?

fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/hansfelix50/L42n3jte/

```js
const options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0
}

const sectionObserverHandler = (entries) => {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      console.log(`${entry.target.className} is visible.`)
    }
  }
}

this.sectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
  sectionObserverHandler,
  options
)

// Observe each section
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.step')
sections.forEach((section) => {
  this.sectionObserver.observe(section)
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px
}

.step1 {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh
}

.step2 {
  /*margin-top: 1px;*/
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh
}
```

```html
<div class="step step1"></div>
<div class="step step2"></div>
```

Comment: If i understood your problem correctly, you want 2nd `console.log` statement to execute only when the blue `div` is in the view completely. If that's correct, then you need to change the `threshold` to 1: `threshold: 1`

Comment: @Yousaf thanks for your response, I want 2nd to `console.log`  when at least 1 pixel is visible on the viewport.

Comment: @Yousaf I tried, but it didn't work https://jsfiddle.net/hansfelix50/rhonv64y/3/

Comment: [Demo](https://jsbin.com/wubisimure/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)